# changing text input from dropdown does not update selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an text input that automatically changes the text in a div using keyup. The issue is, the user also needs to be able to select an option from a dropdown and have that update as well.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcdevelopment/w3tu5/18/

I use the following to update the div with no issue, yet when a dropdown is selected, nothing changes. Any suggestions?

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
            $('._name').text($('#name').val());
        });
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/w3tu5/19/?

Comment: Close, but it does not update the text field. I was able to do that as well.

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/w3tu5/22/)

```
 $('.drop').change(function () {
            $('._name').text($('.drop').val());
            $('#name').val($('.drop').val());
        });
```

Comment: you'll get a tick sign under the downvote button, click on it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3tu5/21/)**

Check this code, you need to change text of `._name` too,

For input text,

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
    $('._name').text($(this).val());
});
```

And for `<select>`

```
$('.drop').change(function () {
     $('._name').text($(this).val());
     $('#name').val($(this).val());
});
```

*Side Note* : Use `$(this)` to get the context of the current element, instead of using a selector repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this. Here's one:

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {            
    $('._name').text($('#name').val());
    $('.drop option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop("selected", true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gDsuu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of the input does fire the keyup event.

You just need to fire it yourself:

```
$('.drop').change(function () {
    $('#name').val($('.drop').val());
    $('#name').keyup();
});
```

or create a function that updates the label content:

```
function updateLabel(){
    $('._name').text($('#name').val());
}
```

and call it from the keyup event handler and the drop down change event handler:

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
    updateLabel();
});

$('.drop').change(function () {
    $('#name').val($('.drop').val());
    updateLabel();
});
```